# Reading CSV file in R and formatting dates and time while reading and avoiding missing values marked as?

Tags: r

I am trying to Reading CSV file in R . How can I read and format dates and times while reading and avoid missing values marked as ?. The data I load after reading should be clean.

I tried something like
`data <- read.csv("Data.txt")`
It worked, but the dates and times were as is.

Also how can I extract a subset of data from specific data range?

For this I tried something like

```
subdata <- subset(data, 
                  Date== 01/02/2007 & Date==02/02/2007, 
                  select = Date:Sub_metering_3)
```

I get error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Date' not found`

Date is the first column.

Comment: Are your date values a proper R `Date` or `POSIXt` class? By default R will read them in as factors. You need to make sure you've converted them to date values and then you can do comparisons with `x>as.Date("2007-01-01")` or something similar

Comment: Yet another example from the Johns Hopkins Data Science course. I'm trying to solve it myself.

Answer (score 16):

The functions `read.csv()` and `read.table()` are not set up to do detailed fancy conversion of things like dates that can have many formats. When these functions don't automatically do what's wanted, I find it best to read the data in as text and then convert variables after the fact.

```
data <- read.csv("Data.txt",colClasses="character",na.strings="?")
data$FixedDate <- as.Date(data$Date,format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

or whatever your date format is.  The variable `FixedDate` will then be of type `Date` and you can use equality and other conditions to subset.

Also, in your example code you are putting `01/02/2007` as bare code, which results in dividing 1 by 2 and then by 2007 yielding 0.0002491281, rather than inserting a meaningful date.  Consider `as.Date("2007-01-02")` instead.

Comment: How does using strptime() fit into this kind of process?